# When calling super().save() in overriden save method, model is not updating ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

If I have a model with a field that is a `ManyToManyField`, calling `super().save()` inside of the overidden `save` method, the model object is not getting updated if referenced inside of the `save` method.

**`models.py`**

```
class AddOn(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Invoice(models.Model):
    additional_options = models.ManyToManyField(AddOn)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
        # this prints the objects that were selected prior to the save.
        # this isn't helpful if the selected objects have changed.
        print(self.additional_options.all())
```

Comment: Why does this surprise you? M2Ms are entries in a linking table. You need to change those separately.

Comment: What are you expecting as an output?

Comment: It surprises me because I'm super dumb. I was expecting the output to be the items I selected. When I say "selected" I'm referring to selecting the items in the admin

Comment: Maybe go through [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) again to refresh your memory on how to create m2m relationships. You'll see that saving the model won't do anything to the m2m relationships.

Comment: Also, when calling `super()`, make sure you pass all arguments, they might be important!!! (`super().save(*args, **kwargs)`). This has nothing to do with your issue though.

Comment: The admin site uses model forms to save your models, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)'s how m2m relationships are saved with model forms: **after the instance is saved** the `save_m2m()` method is called.

Comment: Okay so I understand that this is expected behavior now, thank you. But if I need to modify some fields based on the objects that were selected in the admin, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you! I now realize that that is what I was looking for

Comment: You could use the [`m2m_changed` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) if this needs to be done always (regardless if changed in admin site or not). Or you could restrict to the admin site by overriding `save_model()` in your `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: @dirkgroten in the link you shared, it says `save_m2m` is only necessary if the`commit` field of the`save` method is set to false

Comment: Correct, but this was more to illustrate how a form saves the m2m relationships. First the model, then the relationships. My other comment tells you what you should do.